# How can i set a cron job for this particular case

Tags: bash, cron

"Whenever an admin user logs out his home directory,it should be backed up to /backup directory."

Comment: Anything you have tried till now?

Comment: will try in a couple of minutes,thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you can use cron, but you can try to add backup commands to `.bash_logout` file which is located in admin's home.

To start backup in separate process try to use `at`.

```
at now <<EOF
# your commands to backup
EOF
```

Answer (score 2):

Please put any code for backup you want to in file

```
$HOME/.bash_logout
```

Its located in every user's home directory. If its not there then you can create one. But it should be owned by the same user. Not by root.

[Read more](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/files.html)